# Generating unique number sequence for use as entity key for app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Has anyone got any example code for creating a unique number sequence to be used as keys for an entity in a Google app engine datastore?

Would like to use sequential order numbers as the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `db.allocate_ids()` as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#allocate_ids) to generate unique IDs for your entities.

Here's a quick example derived from the example at the above link:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

# get unique ID number - I just get 1 here, but you could get many ...
new_ids = db.allocate_ids(handmade_key, 1)

# db.allocate_ids() may return longs but db.Key.from_path requires an int (issue 2970)
new_id_num = int(new_id[0])

# assign the new ID to an entity
new_key = db.Key.from_path('MyModel', new_id_num)
new_instance = MyModel(key=new_key)
...
new_instance.put()
```

([issue 2970 reference](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2970))

Comment: Or just don't specify a key, and let the datastore generate one for you, which will have exactly the same effect.

Comment: @NickJohnson, that's [no longer true](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html) as of  the 1.8.1 release of Google App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [How to implement "autoincrement" on Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985812) where you find a implementation of sequence numbers.