# How to implement "autoincrement" on Google AppEngine

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I have to label something in a "strong monotone increasing" fashion. Be it Invoice Numbers, shipping label numbers or the like.

1. A number MUST NOT BE used twice
2. Every number SHOULD BE used when exactly all smaller numbers have been used (no holes).

Fancy way of saying: I need to count 1,2,3,4 ...
The number Space I have available are typically 100.000 numbers and I need perhaps 1000 a day.

I know this is a hard Problem in distributed systems and often we are much better of with GUIDs. But in this case for legal reasons I need "traditional numbering".

Can this be implemented on Google AppEngine (preferably in Python)?

Comment: I learn from the answers 1) getting really 'sequentially increasing numbers' (e.g. needed for invoice numbers) is slow and hard. 2) If you lift the (no gaps) requirement (e.g. for parcel numbers), there are are lots of games you can play.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you absolutely have to have sequentially increasing numbers with no gaps, you'll need to use a single entity, which you update in a transaction  to 'consume' each new number. You'll be limited, in practice, to about 1-5 numbers generated per second - which sounds like it'll be fine for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! If I weaken the no-Gaps (2.) requirement what are the alternatives? Unfortunately my number needs come in bursts of 33 a time (a truckload with 33 Pallets http://blogs.23.nu/disLEXia/2007/12/antville-16865/#).

Comment: Come to think of it: It's o problem to consume 33 numbers at once in one transaction. Still: I wonder what the alternatives for the 1 Requirement are.

Comment: If they don't have to be sequential, you can simply use the datastore's built in ID generation functionality. See allocate_ids on this page for details: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html

Comment: If you need to generate your key/nextval more than 5 times a second, read Sharding Counters https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Comment: @KenH Sharded counters cannot be used to generate monotonically increasing IDs.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Can I ask why not?  I mean what's the difference between a single entity counter and a sharded value spread across entities?

Comment: @SaadAttieh There's no atomicity guarantee between different shards of a sharded counter - that's where they get their speedup. You can't guarantee your ID is unique unless you can enforce atomicity across the whole counter; two different shards could be updated simultaneously, generating the same ID.

Comment: You would need to read all shards, increment the lowest one, then return the new sum inside a transaction.

Answer (score 7):

If you drop the requirement that IDs must be strictly sequential, you can use a hierarchical allocation scheme. The basic idea/limitation is that transactions must not affect multiple storage groups.

For example, assuming you have the notion of "users", you can allocate a storage group for each user (creating some global object per user). Each user has a list of reserved IDs. When allocating an ID for a user, pick a reserved one (in a transaction). If no IDs are left, make a new transaction allocating 100 IDs (say) from the global pool, then make a new transaction to add them to the user and simultaneously withdraw one. Assuming each user interacts with the application only sequentially, there will be no concurrency on the user objects.

Answer (score 7):

The [gaetk - Google AppEngine Toolkit](https://github.com/mdornseif/appengine-toolkit) now comes with a simple library function to get a number in a sequence. It is based on Nick Johnson's transactional approach and can be used quite easily as a foundation for Martin von Löwis' sharding approach:

```
>>> from gaeth.sequences import * 
>>> init_sequence('invoce_number', start=1, end=0xffffffff)
>>> get_numbers('invoce_number', 2)
[1, 2]
```

The functionality is basically implemented like this:

```
def _get_numbers_helper(keys, needed):
  results = []

  for key in keys:
    seq = db.get(key)
    start = seq.current or seq.start
    end = seq.end
    avail = end - start
    consumed = needed
    if avail <= needed:
      seq.active = False
      consumed = avail
    seq.current = start + consumed
    seq.put()
    results += range(start, start + consumed)
    needed -= consumed
    if needed == 0:
      return results
  raise RuntimeError('Not enough sequence space to allocate %d numbers.' % needed)

def get_numbers(needed):
  query = gaetkSequence.all(keys_only=True).filter('active = ', True)
  return db.run_in_transaction(_get_numbers_helper, query.fetch(5), needed)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a scalable solution.  The documentation notes that you shouldn't expect to get more that 10 values per second.

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't too strict on the sequential, you can "shard" your incrementer.  This could be thought of as an "eventually sequential" counter.

Basically, you have one entity that is the "master" count.  Then you have a number of entities (based on the load you need to handle) that have their own counters.  These shards reserve chunks of ids from the master and serve out from their range until they run out of values.

Quick algorithm:

1. You need to get an ID.
2. Pick a shard at random.
3. If the shard's start is less than its end, take it's start and increment it.
4. If the shard's start is equal to (or more oh-oh) its end, go to the master, take the value and add an amount `n` to it.  Set the shards start to the retrieved value plus one and end to the retrieved plus `n`.

This can scale quite well, however, the amount you can be out by is the number of shards multiplied by your `n` value.  If you want your records to appear to go up this will probably work, but if you want to have them represent order it won't be accurate.  It is also important to note that the latest values may have holes, so if you are using that to scan for some reason you will have to mind the gaps.

#### Edit

I needed this for my app (that was why I was searching the question :P ) so I have implemented my solution.  It can grab single IDs as well as efficiently grab batches. I have tested it in a controlled environment (on appengine) and it performed very well.  You can find the code [on github](https://github.com/kevincox/appengine-sequential-ids).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at how the [sharded counters](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) are made. It may help you. Also do you really need them to be numeric. If unique is satisfying just use the entity keys.

Comment: No, it has to be numeric. I'm given the number space by somebody else (think of UPS or FedEx)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use allocate_ids(), as people have suggested, then creating these entities up front (i.e. with placeholder property values).

```
first, last = MyModel.allocate_ids(1000000)
keys = [Key(MyModel, id) for id in range(first, last+1)]
```

Then, when creating a new invoice, your code could run through these entries to find the one with the lowest ID such that the placeholder properties have not yet been overwritten with real data.

I haven't put that into practice, but seems like it should work in theory, most likely with the same limitations people have already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: Sharding increases the probability that you will get a unique, auto-increment value, but does not guarantee it. Please take Nick's advice if you MUST have a unique auto-incrment.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something very simplistic for my blog, which increments an IntegerProperty, `iden` rather than the Key ID.

I define `max_iden()` to find the maximum `iden` integer currently being used. This function scans through all existing blog posts.

```
def max_iden():
    max_entity = Post.gql("order by iden desc").get()
    if max_entity:
        return max_entity.iden
    return 1000    # If this is the very first entry, start at number 1000
```

Then, when creating a new blog post, I assign it an `iden` property of `max_iden() + 1`

```
new_iden = max_iden() + 1
p = Post(parent=blog_key(), header=header, body=body, iden=new_iden)
p.put()
```

I wonder if you might also want to add some sort of verification function after this, i.e. to ensure the max_iden() has now incremented, before moving onto the next invoice.

Altogether: fragile, inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking in using the following solution: use CloudSQL (MySQL) to insert the records and assign the sequential ID (maybe with a Task Queue), later (using a Cron Task) move the records from CloudSQL back to the Datastore.

The entities also can have a UUID, so we can map the entities from the Datastore in CloudSQL, and also have the sequential ID (for legal reasons).