# Google App Engine Incremental Identifier (ID)

Tags: google-app-engine, key, sequence

I'm building a software for a school hosted at GAE and I need to create and sequence identifier to a new student when created, it doesn't really need to be the "key", but need this number to be incremented by one, each time a new student is added, it's gonna be the student number printed at the school card.

Using the [low level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/index.html), I'm doing this:

```
student = new Entity("student")
student << params.subMap(["name", "birthdate"])
student.save()
```

It's creating the ID but it not been increment by one, it is kind of random...

I also tried to understand the KeyRange, but got nothing out of it.

Some help?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [`Entity`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/index.html) using the `Entity(String kind, String keyName)` constructor:

```
new Entity("student", "" + id);
```

as long as the `id` is unique across all students.

To maintain an increasing counter, just use a normal datastore entity to store the count. The concurrency protections of the datastore (transactions) will neatly ensure sequential entity numbering. Sharded counters wont necessarily give you sequential ids (thanks @Nick Johnson).

One way to fetch by key name is (from [here](http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/appengine-datastore-overview)):

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("student", "" + id)
Entity entity = ds.get(key);
```

Comment: Sharded counters won't provide monotonic increases - sharded counters are more or less what App Engine uses internally to allocate IDs. If it absolutely must be sequential, a standard, non-sharded counter, with its associated update rate limitations, is required.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [How to implement "autoincrement" on Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985812) where you find a Python implementation of sequence numbers.