# Is it guaranteed that numeric auto-incremented ID of new entity always bigger than existing IDs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, auto-increment

Is it guaranteed that auto-incremented ID of new entity always bigger than existing IDs ?

Basically I want to periodically dump entity (e.g. Comment) in background task into big blobs as they get created by customers.

So if there are 100 entities right now I'll store them in blob and create helper entity for this blob like

```
class BlobRange
{
    long fromId;    // Comment.id
    long toId;      // Comment.id
    String blobKey;
}
```

Next time background task would find biggest `BlobRange.toId` and would fetch new chunk of `Comment` whose `id` is greater than `BlobRange.toId`, which in this example would be greater than 100.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, no. IDs seem to be allocated in blocks (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#allocateIds%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29)). I've personally seen IDs allocated something like this: 1001, 2001, 1002, 3001, 2002, etc.. It seems that they are incremented contiguously within a block, but there are several blocks used in parallel.

So you can not rely on this to check for new entities.

Instead use [Query Cursors](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors) for this. Create a timestamp property (can be a unix timestamp of type `long`) on Comment that records when Comment was created. Then use query and cursors to detect new entities.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I do right now. The problem is that I have overlap between two blobs for Comments that were added approximately at the same time at peak loads. I filter duplicates out but thought I could eliminate this minor issue completely.