# Does allocate_ids always returns positive values?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does the allocate_ids function always returns positive values?
Or can it return negative or zero values sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

In a google groups comment somebody called [Stephen](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/_I7KW2X02aI/Drqp7HHhAucJ) says with regard to `db.model`:

> IDs are 64bit positive integers.
>   If you allocate IDs for an entity called 'Sequence' you can use them
>   for any other entity kind, including entities with parents which would
>   otherwise use a unique range if auto allocated. IDs from 'Sequence'
>   will be unique within your datastore, which is a superset of the
>   requirement that IDs be unique per-entity group. However, you must
>   always then use an ID from Sequence and never allow auto-allocation.

He seems to know what he's talking about. I can't find another reference to the Datastore's automatic ID sequence generator but in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542982/is-it-guaranteed-that-numeric-auto-incremented-id-of-new-entity-always-bigger-th/8544624#8544624) here the java definition of [allocateids](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29) gets linked to and it says that it can throw this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - If parent is not a complete key, **if num is less than 1, or if num is greater than 1 billion.**

Comment: Hi, Paul. Thanks for your helpful references. I understand it should not return negative or zero numbers.

Comment: That second reference is out of context - it does not refer to the ID, but to the parameter that specifies how many ID's the fn should return.  Note also that the generated ID's are now limited to 53 bits so as to work well with js integers.