# App Engine datastore + memcache + get a page of data into cache

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking at a way to get a page of data into memcache from datastore.  Basically a **comment system** like Facebook where you load a set of 10 comments at a time. Datastore persists each comment as an object. 
I would load 10 comments into an array object and load that on cache with a page ID suffix for the key by convention.

**Now the problem** : Data store doesn't seem to promise an increment of 1 while creating auto ID's. checked this on SO - [Autoincrement ID in App Engine datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393585/autoincrement-id-in-app-engine-datastore)

Upon eviction, how can I load these 10 comments from datastore into cache of a particular range lets say - page #5 or #6 when I can't access datastore objects by an incremented key ?

Any suggestions are welcome, even if you feel the whole approach is flawed let me know.

I did explore google cloud SQL as an alternative to datastore which takes care of my paging and ID-increment problems, and felt its not the best option as I expect this comments table to grow into very large dataset eventually.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure what the cache has to do with anything. You page through query results from the datastore with a cursor, though.

Comment: I'd throw away the reliance on consecutive IDs or contiguous ID ranges, you'll find it to be a serious obstacle against flexibility and scalability. Instead of thinking about ID ranges just think about explicit lists/arrays of IDs.

Comment: Hi Dan Cornilescu, I too feel the same way about relying on IDs that get auto incremented. My problem is how do you decide as to what range of IDs go into a block of cache that has been evicted out.  As for Daniel's suggestion on paging query results with a cursor, I don't even want to hit the datastore as I would like to get the data I need from cache.