# GAE Ndb: transaction within pre_put_hook ? or how to generate unique id on the fly

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, unique-id

In an Ndb datastore, a given entity has an attribute `num`, which should be a unique id, but contrary to Ndb's native ids, it must not be a huge number, but should be assigned equal to the max of current num values plus one.

In other words, you could assign it this way:

```
last_entity = MyEntity.query().order(-MyEntity.num).get()
max_num = last_entity.num
new_num = max_num + 1
```

And you would want to do this within a @transactional scope, up until you put() the newly created entity.

It would seem a good place to assign the `num` attribute (if not already set) might be in the `_pre_put_hook()`.   But I don't think I could start a transaction within the `_pre_put_hook()` function that would comprise the final put() of the entity.

So how would this best be handled ?

Another approach would be to define a `assign_num_and_put()` function that would open a transaction (say doing a get on a parent entity), then find the max_num, assign max_num + 1 to new entity, and do the put(), all within the transaction.

Comment: If you want this in transaction you should either change the query to ancestor query or use get by key. Why must it not be a huge number? What's the initial number? if the id incremented by 1, how do you prevent 2 entity from having same number? For example 2 entities with initial ID of 1 and 10, if the entity with ID 1 is incremented 10 times, what would happen?

Comment: (1) You are right about the transaction, I omitted the get by key only to simplify the example.  The question is not in doing an Ndb transaction really.  (2) Numbers are not incremented at every put, once a number is assigned, it stays, only new entities are assigned numbers, and furthermore, only if user has not assigned one.  If user assigns one, then unicity is checked.  (3)  Why not a huge number ?   Because we need a number that can be used by humans, such as in "you should have a look at entity #55".

Comment: You are asking for trouble with your approach. Queries are not garunteed to be correct given eventual consitstancy.  I suggest you precompute (still will have problems) or use another service (cloud sql) to generate new numbers for you.  If you have a high rate of new numbers being generated then you will have a number of problems guaranteeing unqiueness and not cause performance problems.  If its a slow creation rate then you will transactionally update a control record (s) which holds the last number updated.  But this still needs to be designed properly.

Comment: @TimHoffman, thank you for the advice.  It's a very slow creation rate, expected around once every minute at most.   I thought this would be quite a common need.   For the moment, I opted for the assign_num_and_put() function, which is transactionnal, and will lock the ancestor entity (actually num numbers are handled separately for each ancestor value), assign a num attribute if none is set, then put().   Seems to work nicely.

Comment: my bad, I misread the code, I thought it's incremented on every put. Here is another way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393585/autoincrement-id-in-app-engine-datastore 

Isn't one day the entity would be a big number anyway as you have more entity? I think you can have another human readable entity, with base64 encoded for example