# App Engine datastore: ID auto increment with NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, auto-increment, datastore

I'm modelling data, which IDs should be with auto increment. Actually, I've made working model, but need some advise from datastore guru.

There is my code for ID generation:

```
class AutoIncrementModel(ndb.Model):
  entity_id = ndb.IntegerProperty('eID')
  def _pre_put_hook(self):
    if self.key and self.key.id(): return
    latest = self.__class__.query().order(-self.__class__.entity_id).get()
    self.entity_id = latest and latest.entity_id + 1 or 1
    while self.__class__.get_by_id(self.entity_id): self.entity_id += 1
    self.key = ndb.Key(self.__class__.__name__, self.entity_id, parent=self.key and self.key.parent() or None)
    self.put()
```

This code generates straightforward IDs, but I'm quite not sure is it good enough.

**UPD**: *This code fails*. Several entities can be written with same key and data can be overwritten.

№1. Can it cause problem with data loss? "While loop" preserves app from generating ID. But I'm not sure there is no possibility for data to be overwritten.

№2. May transaction like this make saving better?

```
  def _pre_put_hook(self):
    def callback():
      while self.__class__.get_by_id(self.entity_id): self.entity_id += 1
      self.key = ndb.Key(self.__class__.__name__, self.entity_id, parent=self.key and self.key.parent() or None)
      self.put()
    if self.key and self.key.id(): return
    latest = self.__class__.query().order(-self.__class__.entity_id).get()
    self.entity_id = latest and latest.entity_id + 1 or 1
    ndb.transaction(callback, xg=True)
```

**UPD**: Transaction helps to avoid data loss. This code seems to work much better than first example.

№3. Is there a way to get max ID from group of entities without extra field for index?

Comment: It's difficult to avoid a race condition in creating sequential IDs on a distributed system, and I don't think your first example succeeds in doing so. At the very least you're going to need to involve a transaction (Although I'm not sure whether your second example works either.) (Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985812/how-to-implement-autoincrement-on-google-appengine although it's possible ndb changes things so I haven't voted to close as duplicate).

Comment: Why do you (think you) need sequential IDs? The datastore comes with a perfectly satisfactory way to generate _unique_ IDs.

Answer (score 3):

Basically this can't be done. You need an external counter "singleton" and should add sharing for performance should you need more than about one write per second. See [How to implement "autoincrement" on Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985812/how-to-implement-autoincrement-on-google-appengine) for an discussion of the options.

Answer (score 0):

does not have sense to order by "self.**class**.entity_id" field beacuse this field is an unique identifier, never has an incremental value, no has sense to add neither.